# Blender 2.8 retargeting BVH Mocap file to a rig - is this implemented in 2.8 yet?

Tags: makehuman, motion-capture, bvh

I have installed the Mhx2 addon into Blender 2.8 and so can now import MakeHuman characters. I also have MB lab installed as an addon. However, I cannot see any way of retargeting a CMU bvh file to any of these rigs. Is this not yet implemented in the Blender 2.8 builds?